# How to edit filters and fields that appear in add custom filter option in a module in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10, odoo

I'm new to odoo, I need to delete some fields that appear when click add a custom filter in a fleet module in odoo 10, and how to add custom filters and delete existing ones?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you want to add your new filter views under the filter menu?@mahmoud alaa

Comment: Yes, I want to remove some of fields that appear when click add custom filter

Answer (score 2):

You can use **field_get()** to change field attribute "**selectable**", which is used in ***search_menu.js*** in ***web*** module to decide what fields to show when clicking "Add Custom Filter. Try this:

```
selectable_fields = ['field1',...]

@api.model
def fields_get(self, allfields=None, attributes=None):
    res = super(YourModel, self).fields_get(allfields, attributes=attributes) 
    not_selectable_fields = set(self._fields.keys()) - set(self.selectable_fields)
    for field in not_selectable_fields:
        res[field]['selectable'] = False
    return res
```

Related code in ***search_menu.js***:

```
get_fields: function () {
    if (!this._fields_def) {
        this._fields_def = data_manager.load_fields(this.searchview.dataset).then(function (data) {
            var fields = {
                id: { string: 'ID', type: 'id', searchable: true }
            };
            _.each(data, function(field_def, field_name) {
                if (field_def.selectable !== false && field_name !== 'id') {
                    fields[field_name] = field_def;
                }
            });
            return fields;
        });
    }
    return this._fields_def;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this filter to your code.

**For example: To add filter in Sale Order Line.**

```
<record id="inherit_so_line_filter_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.list.available</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_sales_order_line_filter"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search>
            <filter string="Pending" domain="[('remian_qty','&gt;',0)]" name = "qty_available"/>
            <filter string="Lost" domain="[('remian_qty','=',0)]" name = "qty_lost"/>
       </search>
    </field>
 </record>
```

**For example: To add filter using xpath in Sale Order.**

```
<record id="view_sale_order_inherit_search" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">sale.order.search.filter</field>
  <field name="model">sale.order</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.sale_order_view_search_inherit_quotation"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//search" position="inside">
      <filter string="Total &lt; 1000" name="total_under_1000" domain="[('amount_total', '&lt;', 1000)]"/>
      <filter string="Total &gt;= 1000" name="total_above_1000" domain="[('amount_total', '&gt;=', 1000)]"/>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score -1):

Inherit the existing filter like this:

```
<record id="any_id_name" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">model.nameinsearchview</field>
        <field name="model">model.name</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="external_id/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <filter name="that_field_name_in_exisiting_filter_view" position="replace">
            </filter>
        </field>
</record>
```

that's it. Now this will replace the existing code.

Comment: In this field, what I should write                                                                             <field name="name">model.nameinsearchview</field>                                  Do you mean the modelname then . then the search view name? I made this but   it raises error "Element filter name="schoodriver" can't locate in parent view"

Comment: I created a new module and in views.xml wrote :                                               <odoo>
  <data>


      <record id="inheitance_of_fleet_vehicle_filters" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">fleet.vehicle.fleet.vehicle.search</field>
        <field name="model">fleet.vehicle</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="fleet.fleet_vehicle_view_search"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <filter name="schoodriver" position="replace">
            </filter>
        </field>
</record>

  </data>
</odoo>

Comment: I'm sure with model but I think error in this "<field name="name">model.nameinsearchview</field>"

Comment: That is correct only. Oh wait, now I got your mistake here. Go to developer mode, edit search view, copy the view name and paste it in that line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163392/discussion-between-mahmoud-alaa-and-naveen).